# is it better to use shared_ptr.reset or operator =?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

I'm trying to wrap my head around the new idioms for C++11.

It seems that with shared_ptr at least, there is a substantive difference between using `new T()` and `make_shared<T>()`.

But what of resetting a shared pointer to point to a new instance of something.  Previously, I would typically use `reset(new T())` member.  However, doesn't this suffer from the same problem as not using make_shared() in the first place?  (i.e. it doesn't allow make_shared to allocate the object, therefore it is forced to place the ref count in a separate allocation instead of in the same allocation as the T itself?)

Is it simply better going forward to use:

```
mysharedptr = make_shared<T>(args...);
```

Or is there a better way?

And shouldn't reset offer variadic forwarding of arguments as make_shared does, so that one could write `mysharedptr.reset(args...);`?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

There is indeed a substantial difference between:

```
shared_ptr<T> sp(new T());
```

And:

```
shared_ptr<T> sp = make_shared<T>();
```

The first version performs an allocation for the `T` object, then performs a separate allocation to create the reference counter. The second version performs one single allocation for both the object and the reference counter, placing them in a contiguous region of memory, resulting in less memory overhead.

Also, some implementations are able to perform further space optimizations in the case of `make_shared<>` (see the "We Know Where You Live" optimization done by MS's implementation).

However, that is not the only reason why `make_shared<>` exists. The version based on explicit `new T()` is not exception-safe in some situations, especially when invoking a function that accepts a `shared_ptr`.

```
void f(shared_ptr<T> sp1, shared_ptr<T> sp2);

...

f(shared_ptr<T>(new T()), shared_ptr<T>(new T()))
```

Here, the compiler could evaluate the first `new T()` expression, then evaluate the second `new T()` expression, then construct the corresponding `shared_ptr<>` objects. But what if the second allocation causes an exception before the first allocated object is bound to its `shared_ptr<>`? It will be leaked. With `make_shared<>()`, this is not possible:

```
f(make_shared<T>(), make_shared<T>())
```

Because allocated objects are bound to the respective `shared_ptr<>` objects inside each function call to `make_shared<>()`, this call is exception-safe. This is yet another reason why naked `new` should never be used unless you really know what you are doing. (*)

Considering your remark about `reset()`, you are right in observing that `reset(new T())` will perform separate allocations for the counter and the object, just as the construction of a new `shared_ptr<>` will perform a separate allocation when a raw pointer is passed as an argument. Therefore, an assignment using `make_shared<>` is preferable (or even a statement such as `reset(make_shared<T>())`).

Whether or not `reset()` should support a variadic argument list, this is probably more of a kind of open discussion for which StackOverflow is not a good fit.

(*) There are a few situations that still require it. For instance, the fact that the C++ Standard Library lacks a corresponding `make_unique<>` function for `unique_ptr`, so you'll have to write one yourself. Another situation is when you do not want the object and the counter to be allocated on a single memory block, because the presence of weak pointers to the object will prevent the *entire* block from being deallocated, even though no more owning pointers to the object exist.

Comment: I think it's good to note that the exception-safety argument is enough (for me at least) to say we should no longer even use `new` at all, but `make_unique` at a bare minimum. This prevents any possible leaks by design for any allocation.

Comment: @GManNickG: Yes, `make_unique` is the exception I had in mind for allowing the use of `new`. Btw, do you happen to know why there's no `make_unique` in the standard library?

Comment: Simple oversight. Btw, you still might want to *not* use `make_shared` if you're memory-pressed, since the optimization will keep the memory-block itself alive until there are no more weak pointers.

Comment: I wonder though about make_unique<T> vs. unique_ptr<T>::reset?  Isn't there an optimization available in reusing the allocated T?  Couldn't reset (assuming it was variadic and used perfect forwarding) simply reuse the existing memory slot of T?

Comment: @Mordachai, yes, assuming `reset` worked more like a container's `emplace` function it could reuse memory, but that assumption doesn't hold and is a fairly big design change. The C++11 smart pointers are only responsible for taking ownership of an object, not its creation or allocating memory for it. Rather than destroying, deallocating, allocating and constructing, maybe you just want to do `*up = T(args...)` instead?

Comment: Side discussion: I'd go with `shared_ptr<T>::emplace<Args...>(Args&&... args)` rather than overloading `reset`.

Comment: There are also cases where the `make_shared<>()` is not possible such as when the constructor and/or destructor are private (i.e. you created some form of singleton or at least fully controlled allocation/deallocation of your class objects.)

Answer (score 6):

Correct, `reset(new T...)` suffers all the issues of `shared_ptr(new T...)`; it will result in double allocation and also is non-exception-safe (there's not much chance of a leak, unless `bad_alloc` happens within `reset`).

`reset` is documented as equivalent to `shared_ptr<T>(ptr).swap(*this)`, so you could also write:

```
make_shared<T>(args...).swap(mysharedptr);
```

Assignment from `make_shared<T>` is almost equivalent, the only difference being the relative order of the deletion of the old `T` and the destruction of the temporary `shared_ptr`, which is not observable.

Comment: I'm not sure what is best.  But I think for now I am going with your swap for std::unique_ptr and assignment for std::shared_ptr, just because this avoids having to write `myptr = std::move(make_unique<T>(...))`

Comment: @Mordachai the `move` isn't necessary; the return value of `make_shared` or `make_unique` is a prvalue, so binds to a rvalue reference.

Comment: Thanks.  I must've made some other mistake and misunderstood it.  I see now that simple assignment works fine.

Comment: and is required for polymorphic uses `p = make_unique<derived>()`