# C++11 Composite Pattern with Smart Pointers

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11, shared-ptr, composite

I am working on a personal project to familiarize myself with C++11 and Boost.

I have a inheritance relationship with a `UrlExtractor` base class, with a `TagUrlExtractor` derived class and a `CompoundExtractor` derived class. A `CompoundExtractor` can contain any number of `UrlExtractors`, thus implementing the [composite pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern).

I am curious what the method signature for `CompositeExtractor.addExtractor` should look like. Since I'm dealing with a polymorphic type, I am forced to work with pointers (or references). I want to use the new smart pointers, specifically `shared_ptr`.

I tried writing the `addExtractor` member function like this:

```
void addExtractor(shared_ptr<UrlExtractor> extractor);
```

However, I get a compile error if I try to write:

```
compound.addExtractor(new TagUrlExtractor());
```

The issue is that it would take two implicit conversions to create a `shared_ptr<UrlExtractor>`: one to the `UrlExtractor` base class and second to the `shared_ptr`.

I could call the function like this:

```
compound.addExtractor(shared_ptr<UrlExtractor>(new TagUrlExtractor));
```

However, this is very verbose. How is this situation handled normally?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The issue is that it would take two implicit conversions to create a shared_ptr: one to the UrlExtractor base class and second to the shared_ptr

That's not the issue: the issue is that the constructor of `shared_ptr` that accepts a raw pointer is marked as `explicit`, so it can't be used in a copy-initialization context (function parameters are copy-initialized, as specified by § 8.5/15).

You could (and actually, should) use [`std::make_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared):

```
compound.addExtractor(std::make_shared<TagUrlExtractor>());
```

`std::make_shared()` has the advantage of being exception-safe *and* performing one dynamic allocation less than when you are initializing a shared pointer from a `new` expression (also see [this Q&A on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14837300/1932150)).

Comment: That actually eliminates the need to do an explicit `new`. Very nice!

Comment: @TravisParks: Indeed, in C++11 you almost never need to use `new` unless you're doing really low-level memory management (like writing your own container and whatnot), and in C++14 you can remove the "almost" - thanks to `std::make_unique()` ;-)

Comment: @AndyProwl: I would argue that `new` is still pretty commonplace until we get `make_unique` (with `unique_ptr` often being the preferable choice). `delete` on the other hand should be pretty much non existant in C++11 code (good ridence).

Comment: @Grizzly: Well, that's pretty much what I wrote in the previous comment ;)

Comment: @AndyProwl: I may not have formulated that all to well. I wanted to express my opinion that "almost" is much to strong to te current situation.

Comment: @Grizzly: I understand what you mean, but my "almost" is there precisely to cover the creation of `unique_ptr` (as the second part of the sentence implies)