# Assign a newly constructed shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

I encounter a question with `shared_ptr`, it seems that to initialize an empty `shared_ptr`, there are a two common ways as quoted from [std::shared_ptr: reset() vs. assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31438714/stdshared-ptr-reset-vs-assignment)

```
T {
  T(X x, Y y);
  ~T();

}
shared_ptr<T> p;
p.reset(new T(x,y));
p = make_shared<T>(t1) //t1 is a T type object
```

However, why this won't work?

```
 p = shared_ptr<T>(new T(x,y));
```

Is it just a bad practice or it is simply wrong? Thanks!

There is an answer saying that make_shared is more efficient than new in terms of construction  [Is make_shared really more efficient than new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9302296/is-make-shared-really-more-efficient-than-new):

```
std::shared_ptr<Object> p1 = std::make_shared<Object>("foo"); //copy??
std::shared_ptr<Object> p2(new Object("foo")); //conversion?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, why this won't work?
>
> ```
> p = shared_ptr<T>(new T(x,y));
> ```

That's fine. It's used that way in the linked answer.

Converting a `new` expression to `shared_ptr` is unsafe when other subexpressions may throw exceptions. It's possible to get a memory leak, due to unspecified order of evaluation. But `new` as an initializer for a named variable is safe.

> ```
> std::shared_ptr<Object> p1 = std::make_shared<Object>("foo"); //copy??
> std::shared_ptr<Object> p2(new Object("foo")); //conversion?
> ```

The problem is that `shared_ptr` requires a reference count on the heap. `make_shared` is able to combine the shared object and the reference count into a single allocation, whereas the conversion takes a preexisting object and therefore needs to call `new` again just for the count.

Answer (score 0):

> Is `p = shared_ptr<T>(new T())` just a bad practice or it is simply wrong?

You're confusing a NULL pointer with a pointer to a default-constructed object. Neither is "right" or "wrong"; they simply have different semantics and are appropriate in different circumstances.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, do you mind further elaborating on your answer? I think shared_ptr<T> p; will give a null pointer while all the 3 lines following will assign an object to be managed by the pointer while I am trying to figure out the difference between the last one versus previous ones? Sorry if my concepts are completely wrong.