# Why does shared_ptr<int> p; p=nullptr; compile?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, explicit

Since the constructor of `std::shared_ptr` is marked as explicit one, so expressions like `auto p = std::make_shared<int>(1); p = new int(6);` is wrong.

My question is why does [`std::make_shared<int>(1); p = nullptr;` compile](https://godbolt.org/z/bvs1esYv7)?

Here is the aforementioned code snippet:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto p = std::make_shared<int>(1);

    //p = new int(6);

    p = nullptr;

    if(!p)
    {
        std::cout << "not accessable any more" << std::endl;
    }

    p.reset();
}
```

Such code is seen at [std::shared_ptr: reset() vs. assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31438714/stdshared-ptr-reset-vs-assignment)

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr -- there's an overload for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The raw pointer constructor is `explicit` to prevent you accidentally taking ownership of a pointer. As there is no concern taking ownership of `nullptr` the [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) taking `std::nullptr_t` is not marked explicit.

Note that this only applies to `nullptr` these other assignments of a null pointer might not work (depending on your compiler):

```
auto p = std::make_shared<int>(1);
p = NULL;
int * a = nullptr;
p = a;
```

Comment: I suggest you explain *why* `p = NULL` and `p = a` both fail (i.e. because `NULL` and `a` have types distinct from `std::nullptr_t`) and why the initialisation of `a` succeeds (i.e. because `nullptr` can be implicitly converted to an `int *`).

Comment: @Alan Birtles Thank you for the clarificatiion. What's more, as `constexpr shared_ptr() noexcept;` is not `explicit`, so [`std::unique_ptr<int> p = {};`](https://godbolt.org/z/3cxqsxKv9) also works. Am I right>

Comment: @John I assume you mean `std::shared_ptr<int> p = {}`? `explicit` doesn't come into this, that's just calling the default constructor, and `std::shared_ptr<int> p; p = {};` is passing a default constructed `shared_ptr` into the assignment operator

Comment: @Alan Birtles I see, thank you so much. I think `std::shared_ptr<int> p = {}` calls the copy constructor(i.e. `shared_ptr( const shared_ptr& r )` ) other than the default constructor. Am I right?

Comment: @John no, its the default constructor: https://godbolt.org/z/f18daeWKM

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL suggests to me that `NULL` should work, because it is a `std::nullptr_t` constant. godbolt.org agrees with me, BTW. The other assignment missing is with a zero integer literal, that seems to work as well.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt depends on your compiler, `NULL` can be `0` or `nullptr`