# Can std::make_unique be used with abstract interface?

Tags: c++, std, unique-ptr

Consider the following line of code:

```
auto source1 = std::unique_ptr<IGpsSource>(new GpsDevice(comPort, baudrate));
auto source2 = std::unique_ptr<IGpsSource>(new GpsLog(filename));
```

How can that be written using the new `std::make_unique` function, supported by VS 2013?
Is it even possible?*

*My problem is that I don't know how to tell `std::make_unique` what kind of object to instantiate. Because only the constructor's parameters are passed in there seems to be no control over that.

Comment: Isn't it C++14? I thought VS2013 didn't support it

Comment: @MarcoA. VS2013 supports a few C++14 bits, and `make_unique` is one of them.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, you can of course use `make_unique` for that, but it's not as useful as you might want. You have these options:

```
std::unique_ptr<IGpsSource> source1 = std::make_unique<GpsDevice>(comPort, baudrate);
auto source2 = std::unique_ptr<IGpsSource>{ std::make_unique<GpsLog>(filename) };
```

I would say the real question is "why do you want that?"

1. Unlike `make_shared`, `make_unique` has no allocation benefits over `new`. So if you need control of the pointer's type, what you're doing is just fine.
2. Why do you need the pointer to be typed to `IGpsSource` in the first place? An implicit conversion from `std::unique_ptr<Derived>` *rvalues* to `std::unique_ptr<Base>` rvalues exists. So if you're actually calling `make_unique` to initialise an `IGpsSource` pointer, it will work just fine. And if you want to transfer the pointer somewhere, you'll have to `std::move` it anyway, at which point the conversion can happen again.

Comment: Exception safety argument [from this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20895705/673852) still applies to `make_unique`, not only to `make_shared`. So, `make_unique<Xyz>()` should be preferred over `unique_ptr(new Xyz)`.

Comment: @Ruslan Note that the exception safety criterion applies to multiple allocations being done in a single expression. The OP's case is quite different: they have only a single allocation, and want precise control over the pointer's type.

Comment: @ajmal-kunnummai's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49619801/754300) makes more succinct use of `std::make_unique()`.

Answer (score 26):

```
std::unique_ptr<Base> base_ptr = std::make_unique<Derived>();
```

As Angew said, the above should work fine. *Provided* `Derived` uses public inheritance. Just wanted to add that for completeness.