# Casting child shared_pointer to parent shared_pointer c++ 14

Tags: casting, c++14

What is the proper way to up-cast a child shared pointer to its parent shared pointer? The commented section where I'm going from an apple to a fruit, is where I'm unclear.

```
class Fruit
{
};

class Apple : public Fruit
{
};

typedef std::shared_ptr<Fruit> FruitPtr;
typedef std::shared_ptr<Apple> ApplePtr;

int main()
{
    ApplePtr pApple = ApplePtr( new Apple() );

    FruitPtr pFruit = /* what is the proper cast using c++ 14 */
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can to use a [std::static_pointer_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast), it does exactly what you want:

```
class Fruit { };
class Apple : public Fruit { };

int main() {
  std::shared_ptr<Apple> pApple = std::make_shared<Apple>();
  std::shared_ptr<Fruit> pFruit = std::static_pointer_cast<Fruit>(pApple)
  return 0;
}
```

---

On a side note, I'd avoid constructing a `shared_ptr` directly. The tradeoffs of doing that or using `make_shared` can be read on [this cppreference.com page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared). I'd also avoid typedefining `ApplePtr` and `FruitPtr` as you did because it may be confusing to someone reading your code because there is no indication they are shared pointers instead of raw pointers.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use implicit upcasting:

```
FruitPtr pFruit = pApple
```

If you will add breakpoints, you can notice that after this line the strong reference counter increases to 2 (which I assume is what you would like to have happened).

Unrelated comment:
Prefer the usage of make_shared over calling new yourself (read [Difference in make_shared and normal shared_ptr in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20895648/difference-in-make-shared-and-normal-shared-ptr-in-c) as to why)

Comment: Cool, thank you for the added info. Moving from C++98 to C++14 --- it's quite the change

Comment: However, I need to put the child into a vector<Fruit>, and the compiler is complaining --- so it looks like I do need a cast of some sort.

Comment: @pyInTheSky I hope you are talking about a `vector<FruitPtr>` instead of a `vector<Fruit>`

Comment: #Leonardo, indeed.