# When should I prefer `shared_ptr` to `make_shared`?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, make-shared

As pointed in answers to [Difference in make_shared and normal shared_ptr in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20895648/difference-in-make-shared-and-normal-shared-ptr-in-c), `make_shared` outperforms `shared_ptr` in most cases.

Then why does C++ standard define both `shared_ptr` and `make_shared` together? Are there any cases at which I should prefer `shared_ptr` to `make_shared` or even at which I can only use `shared_ptr` but not `make_shared`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the situations is that [std::make_shared](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) does not support the specifying of the custom deleter.

> Unlike the `std::shared_ptr` constructors, `std::make_shared` does not allow a custom deleter.

You can only do it with the constructor of [std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr), e.g.

```
std::shared_ptr<Foo> sh5(new Foo, [](auto p) {
   std::cout << "Call delete from lambda...\n";
   delete p;
});
```

Another issue is just as the linked post explained, `std::make_shared` performs only one allocation for both the control block and the object pointed to. That means after the object being destroyed, the memory it occupied might not be deallocated immediately. That might cause some memory usage issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you declare class with a private constructor (singleton pattern) you could not use `make_shared` to construct it, but could use `shared_ptr` cast.