# Access private constructor from public static member function using shared_ptr in C++

Tags: c++, class, shared-ptr

Consider the following code where I'd like to delegate the creation of an `A` object to a method called `make`, in order to allow users of the class to only create instances wrapped in a `std::shared_ptr`:

```
#include <memory>

class A {
private:    
    A() {}

public:
    static std::shared_ptr<A> make() {
        return std::make_shared<A>();
    }
};

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<A> a = A::make();
    return 0;
}
```

I would have thought that, because `make` is a member function, it would be allowed to access the private constructor, but apparently that's not the case. Compiling the program fails with the following message in the source of `std::shared_ptr`:

```
/usr/include/c++/8/ext/new_allocator.h:136:4: error: ‘A::A()’ is private within this context
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: You could consider using the [pass key idiom](https://gist.github.com/RklAlx/6727537).

Comment: This has nothing to do with the function being static. It's that `std::make_shared` is trying to construct an `A`, which it can't because the constructor is private.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class A {
private:
    A() {}

public:
    static std::shared_ptr<A> make() {
        return std::shared_ptr<A>(new A());
    }
};
```

Comment: You lose the [benefits of make_shared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20895705/856199) if you do that.

Comment: The downside being two memory allocations, one for the shared_ptr control block, and one for the class A instance object.  In contrast to `std::make_shared` which only will do one allocation for both the control block and object.  May or may not be important, depending on the project and usage pattern.

Comment: This is a clone of [this almost eight year old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8147101/2311167)