# inheritance C++ why father constructor is not evoked

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I just want to test an inheritance pattern but it seems I lacks some understanding. I thought father class's constructor should be evoked. Some direction is apprecitated

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>


template<class Gender, class Race, class ChildType>
class Father 
{
public:
    Father() {
       std::cout << "var = " << ChildType::var   << std::endl;
    };
};


class Male {
public:

};

class Vietnam {
public:


};

class Worker {
public:

};


class Child : public Father<Male, Vietnam, Child>
{
  public:
    static int var;
};

int Child::var(10);


int main() {

  std::shared_ptr<Father<Male, Vietnam, Child>> child(Child());

return 1;
}
```

Comment: Most vexing parse.

Comment: Anyway, it's not clear what you expect `child(Child())` to do, even if it did what you think... `shared_ptr` needs a dynamically allocated instance, not a value, and you should use `std::make_shared()` to get that.

Comment: I think I am getting to the point too. Shared_ptr requires an instance initialization somewhere

Comment: so... Child() alone is not an instantiation? I've just tried new Child() and it does initialize an instance. Thank you for the answer by the way

Comment: @TSL_: a `shared_ptr` takes a pointer for initialization. `make_shared` creates a `shared_ptr` instance initialized with a pointer to a dynamically allocated object.

Comment: @TSL_: [Difference in make_shared and normal shared_ptr in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20895648/315052)

Comment: @jxh: thank you for pointing it out such a comprehensive post. I'll have to read it slowly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code declares a function called `child` returning a `shared_ptr` which is not what you hoped for:

```
std::shared_ptr<Father<Male, Vietnam, Child>> child(Child());
```

You may fix it with this:

```
auto p = make_shared <Father<Male, Vietnam, Child>>();
```

Comment: yes.. I got it. Thanks for the help