# Raw pointer to shared_ptr bug

Tags: c++, c++17, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I'm working on a image treating application.

In summary, I have a byte buffer which stores the image data, so I can use this array to handle the image easily in wx widgets and OpenCV. I planned to store this byte buffer in a shared_ptr as it will be used in other instances of the same class along the execution.

With raw pointer it works properly, but whenever I tried to use shared_ptr I'm having an segmentation fault whenever passing this pointer to a function.

How can I pass it to this function without segmentation fault? it doesn't make sense to me this crashing

The bug is here

```
_dataSize = (size_t)len;
_originalData = std::make_shared<void*>(malloc(_dataSize));
if ( file.Read(_originalData.get(), _dataSize) != len )
```

on the last line of above code, I'm trying to pass the _original data pointer to Read function

Here's the [full code](https://github.com/joaogouveia89/CPPND-ImageBluring), on the piece above, I just put the line that the bug is happening. On the full the code the bug is on src/Img.cpp file on line 18

Thank you

Comment: You don't make an allocation in the parameter passed to `make_shared`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20895648/difference-in-make-shared-and-normal-shared-ptr-in-c

Comment: And if you pass pointer generated by `malloc`, you have to pass a deleter which call `free`.

Comment: Do you really want to have shared ownership of the `void*`, or do you want shared ownership of the object that the `void*` points to?

Comment: `make_shared<T>(arguments)` creates a new shared object of type `T` from `arguments`. `shared_ptr<T>(p)` takes ownership of the object pointed to by `p`.

Comment: In this case I want a shared ownership as during the runtime, it will be make copies of this buffer to other Img objects

Comment: Shared ownership of what? As it stands you are sharing ownership of a *pointer*

Comment: Shared ownership of buffer(_originalData). Maybe the pointer is not the best approach, but even storing a shared_ptr of void I'm having problems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_originalData.get()` is a `void**`, not a `void*`.

To share ownership of that allocation, you need `std::shared_ptr<void>`, not `std::shared_ptr<void*>`. You also need to set the deallocation function, as it is undefined behaviour to `delete` a pointer that was `malloc`ed.

```
_originalData = std::shared_ptr<void>{ malloc(len), free }; // _originalData is a `std::shared_ptr<void>
if ( file.Read(_originalData.get(), len) != len )
```

Alternatively, since C++20, you could use a `std::shared_ptr<char[]>`, and not use `malloc` at all.

```
_originalData = std::make_shared_for_overwrite<char[]>{ len }; // _originalData is a `std::shared_ptr<char[]>
if ( file.Read(*_originalData, len) != len ) // implicit conversion of char* to void*
```

Comment: Nice. I'll try your answer and give here a feedback. Thank you very much

Comment: On this project, I cannot use C++20 for reasons that are not in my power to decide. But your solution on defining a delete function works, I did tried something similar previously, but on the declaration of shared_ptr, which seems to be not allowed. Btw, I implement your suggestion and it worked well, and also I save the C++20 code to use it preferably, when possible. Thank you very much again

Comment: `std::make_shared_for_overwrite` - wasn't aware of that, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on [what make_shared does](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared).

It will try to Contruct an objet of type `T` sending the arguments you give to the constructor.

In your code, it will try to create **a new** `void*` object (passing `malloc`s retunr pointer as argument), which I believe you don't want to do.

Instead if you use the `shared_pointer`'s object constructor descibed [here on 3-7](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) it

> Constructs a shared_ptr with ptr as the pointer to the managed object.

Which I think you want to do

Comment: I think Caleth's answer is the one, just leaving this here with references :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I'll try it later.