# How to get rid of incompatible c++ conversion

Tags: c++, stl, namespaces, std

I'm getting the following error during compilation:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2664   'mytest::Test::Test(const mytest::Test &)': cannot convert argument 1 from '_Ty' to 'const mytest::Test &'  TotalTest   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\xutility    158
```

I have no idea what is, so I'm putting the code here to exemplify what was being done:

**TotalTest.cpp**

```
include <iostream>

#include "Test.h"

using namespace mytest;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";

    new Test();
}
```

**Test.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "Test.h"
#include <iostream>

namespace mytest
{
    using namespace std;

    class Test
    {
    public:
        Test();
        ~Test();

        shared_ptr<Test> t;

    };
}
```

**Test.cpp**

```
#include "Test.h"

namespace mytest
{

    Test::Test()
    {
    }

    Test::~Test()
    {
    }

}
```

**TestFactory.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "Test.h"
#include <iostream>

namespace mytest
{
    using namespace std;

    class TestFactory
    {
    public:
        TestFactory();

        shared_ptr<Test> CreateTest(int testClass);
    };

}
```

**TestFactory.cpp**

```
#include "TestFactory.h"

namespace mytest 
{
    TestFactory::TestFactory()
    {
    }

    shared_ptr<Test> TestFactory::CreateTest(int testClass)
    {
        return make_shared<Test>(new Test());
    }
}
```

I'm using Visual Studio C++ language standard: ISO C++14 Standard (/std:c++14)

Comment: Remove `new test()`

Comment: @Taekahn `new Test()` in `main()` is certainly a mistake (a memory leak at runtime), but it is not the cause of the compiler error.

Comment: @RemyLebeau it’s an error In Make_shared since he is calling a nonexistent copy constructor

Comment: @Taekahn I know, that's why I said as much

Comment: Well, that’s why I said as much too…

Comment: @Taekahn OK, you didn't make it obvious that you were referring to the `new Test()` in `TestFactory::CreateTest()` rather than the `new Test()` in `main()`

Comment: @RemyLebeau in all honesty, I didn’t notice there is one in main. I’m on a tiny phone.

Comment: Thank you guys such a simple syntax problem! the error is not much helpful since I searched for it and not much info was available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `TestFactory::CreateTest()`, `make_shared<Test>(new Test())` is wrong, as `Test` does not have a constructor that accepts a `Test*` pointer as input.

You need to use `make_shared<Test>()` instead, letting `make_shared()` call the default `Test()` constructor for you:

```
shared_ptr<Test> TestFactory::CreateTest(int testClass)
{
    return make_shared<Test>();
}
```

Any parameters you pass to `make_shared()` are passed to the constructor of the type specified in the template argument. In this case, there are no parameters needed.

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from the following line:

```
return make_shared<Test>(new Test());
```

There are 2 ways of initializing a `std::shared_ptr`:

1. Using the `std::shared_ptr` constructor directly, which requires you to pass a `Test` object already allocated on the heap, e.g.:

   ```
    std::shared_ptr<Test> p{ new Test() };
   ```
2. Using `make_shared()`, which performs the heap allocation internally, e.g.:

   ```
    std::shared_ptr<Test> p{ std::make_shared<Test>() };
   ```

   Where in the parentheses you can pass parameters to the constructor of `Test`.

The 2nd option is usually prefered. You can see more info here: [Difference in make_shared and normal shared_ptr in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20895648/)

In addition:

1. `Test.h` should not include itself (it has `#include "Test.h"` at the top).
2. You should avoid using `using namespace std;`. More info here: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/)