# How to prove c++11 make_shared() can keep shared_ptr's control block alive even after its dtor?

Tags: c++, reference, shared-ptr, weak-ptr, make-shared

My question is: is there a case that share_ptr ref count is 0, while weak_ptr ref count is **not** 0?

[Difference in make_shared and normal shared_ptr in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20895648/difference-in-make-shared-and-normal-shared-ptr-in-c)

Referr this thread, showing that if a shared_ptr is created by `make_shared` and there's weak_ptr, its control block will be alive `until`  both shared_ptr and weak_ptr's ref count gets 0. It says:

> There must be a way for weak_ptrs to determine if the managed object is still valid (eg. for lock). They do this by checking the number of shared_ptrs that own the managed object, which is stored in the control block. The result is that the control blocks are alive until the shared_ptr count and the weak_ptr count both hit 0.

---

I had a quick test. I hope the `shared_ptr` created by `make_shared`, if there's weak_ptr pointing to it, its `control block` will still hold sth after shared_ptr is destructed.

```
#include<memory>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct My {
    int m_i;
    My(int i) : m_i(i) { cout << "My ctor:" << m_i << '\n';}
    ~My() { cout << "My ctor:" << m_i << '\n';}
};
weak_ptr<My> wp1, wp2;
int main() {
    {
        auto sp1 = shared_ptr<My>(new My(30));
        wp1 = weak_ptr<My>(sp1);
    }
    cout<< wp1.use_count() << endl;
    {
        auto sp2 = make_shared<My>(40);
        wp2 = weak_ptr<My>(sp2);
    }
    cout<< wp2.use_count() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Both `use_count` will print `0`, my program didn't seems to show whether the `control blocks` is alive or not.

So, how can we prove that `The result is that the control blocks are alive until both shared_ptr and weak_ptr's ref count gets 0`?

Any sample code that could test/prove this theory?

Comment: *So, how can we prove that The result is that the control blocks are alive until both shared_ptr and weak_ptr's ref count gets 0?*  You could look at the C++ documentation which says that's how it works, or you could look at any compiler's shared_ptr implementation which should be compliant with the C++ standard and work that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code couldn't prove, because sp1,sp2 are local variables, they will be released when they out of range. And you could use hook or froce jump to show the result you want to see, but it's not easy.
We could read the source code of weak_ptr, so we can know about what really does, the souce code of weak_ptr is too much, we just view the key segment:

```
  // The actual weak_ptr, with forwarding constructors and
  // assignment operators.
  template<typename _Tp>
    class weak_ptr
    : public __weak_ptr<_Tp>
    {
     
    };
```

From the code, we could see that most work are done by the father class __weak_ptr, that's view the code of __weak_ptr:

```
template<typename _Tp, _Lock_policy _Lp>
    class __weak_ptr
    {
    public:
      
      
      template<typename _Tp1>
        __weak_ptr(const __shared_ptr<_Tp1, _Lp>& __r)
    : _M_ptr(__r._M_ptr), _M_refcount(__r._M_refcount) // never throws
        { __glibcxx_function_requires(_ConvertibleConcept<_Tp1*, _Tp*>) }
 
 
      long
      use_count() const // never throws
      { return _M_refcount._M_get_use_count(); }
 
    
      _Tp*            _M_ptr;         // Contained pointer.
      __weak_count<_Lp>  _M_refcount;    // Reference counter.
    };
```

When we call the use_count() of weak_ptr, we call _M_refcount._M_get_use_count(), _M_refcount was assigned in the constructor of class __weak_ptr , in the assign list we could see _M_refcount(__r._M_refcount), so we should know what really does in the constructor of __weak_count:

```
template<_Lock_policy _Lp>
    class __weak_count
    {
    public:
      
      __weak_count(const __shared_count<_Lp>& __r)
      : _M_pi(__r._M_pi) // nothrow
      {
    if (_M_pi != 0)
      _M_pi->_M_weak_add_ref();
      }
      
    
      long
      _M_get_use_count() const // nothrow
      { return _M_pi != 0 ? _M_pi->_M_get_use_count() : 0; }
 
    
    private:
      friend class __shared_count<_Lp>;
 
      _Sp_counted_base<_Lp>*  _M_pi;
    };
```

In the constructor of class __weak_count the member _M_pi is assigned by the member _M_pi of shared_ptr, and we view the function _M_get_use_count(), when we call use_count() of weak_ptr, in fact we call the use_count() of shared_ptr,  weak_ptr don't have the _Sp_counted_base itself, it`s the _Sp_counted_base of shared_ptr, so the weak_ptr must rely on the shared_ptr.

Let's get back to your question: "Is there a case that share_ptr ref count is 0, while weak_ptr ref count is not 0?"

I think using the normal way to write the code, the answer is NO !

Comment: Examining the source code of a standard library implementation only proves something about *that* implementation. You cannot draw generic conclusions about the language, you can't know whether this is an implementation specified behavior or a required behavior. Additionally, standard library implementations don't follow the same rules as user code. They target specific platforms or tool chains and can rely on non-portable and undefined behavior. While it may be an interesting activity, it isn't a reliably way to learn about C++.

Comment: I don't agree with you , the best and fastest way to lean the C++ is reading the source code step by step, writting the code line by line，not to reading the C++ standard reference files or something Bible, it's not a good way to hold a codeing language.

Comment: Reading C++ source code is a fine way to learn about programming in C++, but insufficient on its own. You always have to be very careful, C++ is notorious for its Undefined Behavior and it is easy to make incorrect assumptions when learning by reading code. The problem is orders of magnitude greater for standard library code, which can use code that is normally Implementation Defined or Undefined Behavior or otherwise must not be used for user code. It is not possible to know, just by reading standard library source code, whether the same code or technique can be used for your own code or not.

Comment: Yes you are right, thinking about the code on different platform, undefined behavior is necessary , but for the application of weak_ptr and shared_ptr  must meet the requirement of  C++ standard,  different  platform should have the same principle  in coding, they should have the similar logic，similar solution.  I notice that the weak_ptr could not be used independly,  must be transported to a shared_ptr，so I  guess     the weak_ptr and shard_ptr should have common part, I dare to say  for other platfom they have the similar application probably, last I have to give the answer a  clear results

Answer (score 5):

This is not a "theory" that needs to be "proven". It is true by *fiat*; the standard requires that `weak_ptr` know when all `shared_ptr`s they are linked to are destroyed. This is necessitated by the requirements of `weak_ptr::lock`. And the only viable way to implement that (without also violating thread safety guarantees, or providing them in incredibly bad ways) is to have a block of memory that is owned by both the weak and shared pointers which is only disposed of when all have been destroyed.

If you wish to see this demonstrated, you can pass the `shared_ptr`'s constructor a user-defined allocator type. `shared_ptr` will use this to allocate the control block for the `shared_ptr`. The control block will only be deleted when the last shared or weak pointer is destroyed. You can do the same for `allocate_shared`.