# noexcept while defining a share ptr

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I got this error  :

> error: no matching function for call to 'Company::Company(Company*)'
> 145 |  noexcept(noexcept(::new((void *)__p)
> |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   146 |        _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...)))
> |        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Test.cpp:20:5: note: candidate: 'Company::Company(int, int)'    20 |     Company(int
> companyId,int value):companyId(companyId),value(value){
> |     ^~~~~~~ Test.cpp:20:5: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided Test.cpp:9:7: note: candidate: 'constexpr
> Company::Company(const Company&)'
> 9 | class Company{
> |       ^~~~~~~ Test.cpp:9:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Company*' to 'const Company&' Test.cpp:9:7: note:
> candidate: 'constexpr Company::Company(Company&&)' Test.cpp:9:7: note:
> no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Company*' to 'Company&&'

The shared pointer gives me an error, I have no idea what the reason is, any idea  please?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory> 

using namespace std;

class Company{
    public:
    int companyId;
    int value;
    int HighestSalaryEmployee;
    int highestSalary;
    int LowestIDHighestSalaryEmployee;
    int lowestSalary;
    int numEmployees;
    public:
    
    Company(int companyId,int value):companyId(companyId),value(value){

        HighestSalaryEmployee=11;
        highestSalary=0;
        LowestIDHighestSalaryEmployee=112;
        numEmployees=0;
    }

};


int main()
{
    shared_ptr<Company> ptr1 = make_shared<Company>(new Company(123456,100));
}
```

Comment: See correct way of using `make_shared`: [Difference in make_shared and normal shared_ptr in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20895648/difference-in-make-shared-and-normal-shared-ptr-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with `noexcept` and everything to do with using `std::make_shared` correctly. The way `std::make_shared` works is similar to how various `emplace` functions work: You pass the arguments used to construct the specified type, and it constructs them.

So what the error message is trying to tell you is that it's attempting to construct a `Company` out of a `Company*`, and `Company` doesn't have any constructors that go from a `Company*` to a `Company`.

The solution is to drop the `new Company(...)` and simply pass the arguments directly:

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<Company> ptr1 = std::make_shared<Company>(123456,100);
```