# How to use 'make_ptr<T>()' while T is a class with private construction?

Tags: c++11, shared-ptr, friend-function

I was working with singleton pattern and shared_ptr.I was trying to make the code like this:

```
class A{
    private:
        static std::shared_ptr<A> instance;
        A();
    public:
        static std::shared_ptr<A> creatInstance();
};

std::shared_ptr<A> A::creatInstance(){
    if(!instance){
        instance=std::make_shared<A>();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

But I got a compiler error.
Any thoughts?
I tried to make make_shared be a friend function of class A,but it didn't work.

```
friend shared_ptr<A> make_shared<A>();
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that std::make_shared< A > requires public constructor of A.

Here is a few solutions of this problem - [How do I call ::std::make_shared on a class with only protected or private constructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147027/how-do-i-call-stdmake-shared-on-a-class-with-only-protected-or-private-const)