# How can I access a protected constructor from a friend function?

Tags: c++, friend-function

I created a class and I want to force anyone who's trying to construct an object, to use `unique_ptr`. To do that I thought of declaring the constructor `protected` and use a `friend` function that returns a `unique_ptr`. So here's an example of what I want to do:

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
public:
    friend std::unique_ptr<A<T>> CreateA<T>(int myarg);

protected:
    A(int myarg) {}
};

template <typename T>
std::unique_ptr<A<T>> CreateA(int myarg)
{
    // Since I declared CreateA as a friend I thought I
    // would be able to do that
    return std::make_unique<A<T>>(myarg);
}
```

I did some reading on friend functions and I understood that a friend function provides access to private/protected members of an object of a class.

---

Is there anyway I can make my example work?

Even without friend functions, my goal is to make the `CreateA` the **only** way for someone to create an object.

**EDIT**

I change the code a bit. I didn't mention that my class takes one template parameter. That makes things more complex apparently.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147027/how-do-i-call-stdmake-shared-on-a-class-with-only-protected-or-private-const

Comment: What's the purpose of the friend method here?  If your only goal is to keep others from using the constructor, simply making it private or protected (if you want to inherit this class later) is sufficient.

Comment: see also "named constructor"

Comment: In your question, `A<T>>` always has a constructor taking `int` . Is this also true in the real code; or does the real code have constructor taking `T` (and perhaps more arguments) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way :-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;
class A
{
    int arg;
public:
    friend unique_ptr<A> CreateA(int myarg);
    void showarg() { cout<<arg; }

protected:
    A(int myarg): arg(myarg) {}
};
unique_ptr<A> CreateA (int myarg)
{
    return std::unique_ptr<A>(new A(myarg));
}
int main()
{
    int x=5;
    unique_ptr<A> u = CreateA(x);
    u->showarg();
    return 0;
}
```

Output :-

```
5
```

If you don't want to use `friend` function you can make the function `static` & call it like this :-

```
unique_ptr<A> u = A::CreateA(x);
```

EDIT :-

In reply to your edit I rewrote the program & it goes like this :-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;
template <typename T>
class A
{
    T arg;
public:
    static std::unique_ptr<A> CreateA(T myarg)
    {
        return std::unique_ptr<A>( new A(myarg) );
    }
    void showarg()
    {
        cout<<arg;
    }
protected:
    A(T myarg): arg(myarg) {}
};

int main()
{
    int x=5;
    auto u = A<int>::CreateA(x);
    u->showarg();
    return 0;
}
```

Simple & easy !!! But remember you cannot instantiate the `object of A`. Good Luck !!!

Comment: That seems to work but having a template parameter for `class A` makes things more complex. I updated my question to include that.

Comment: It works with your edit but I noticed something really strange! If instead of returning a `unique_ptr` using the `new` I do this: `return std::make_unique<A>(myarg)` I get an error. Isn't that strange? I mean, I thought `make_unique` just calls `new` and returns a `unique_ptr`. I am confused.

Comment: `make_unique` uses the `return unique_ptr<T> (new T(...))` statement

Comment: no because `make_unique` acts like it's instantiating object of the class & hence fails.

Comment: Ooh okay got it! Thank you.

Comment: The reason `make_unique<A>(myarg)` fails is because `make_unique` is not a friend, so it cannot invoke the protected constructor

Answer (score 2):

Create a static function that instantiates the protected constructor.

```
  #include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<math.h>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;
template< typename T >
class A
{
public:
    static void CreateA(int myarg, std::unique_ptr<A<T>>& objA, T t) {
        std::unique_ptr<A<T>> objB(new A(myarg, t));
        objA = std::move(objB);
    }

protected:
    A(int myarg, T t) {
        m_t = t;
    }

private:
    T m_t;
};

int main() {

    int myArg = 0;
    std::unique_ptr<A<int>> anotherObjA;
    A<int>::CreateA(myArg, anotherObjA, myArg);


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answers suggest using a static template function, which I agree is the best solution, because it is simpler.

My answer explains why your friend approach didn't work and how to use the friend approach correctly.

---

There are two problems in your original code. One is that `make_unique` is not actually a friend of `A`, so the call `make_unique<A<T>>(myarg);` does not have access to `A`'s protected constructor.  To avoid this , you can use `unique_ptr<A<T>>(new A(myarg))` instead.  Theoretically it would be possible to declare `make_unique` a friend but I'm not even sure of the right syntax for that.

The other issue is [the template friends problem](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#template-friends). Inside a class template, `friend  <function-declaration>` actually declares a non-template friend.

The C++ FAQ suggests two possible workarounds. One of them is to *define* the friend function inline. However, in that case the function can *only* be found by argument-dependent lookup. But since the function does not take `A<T>` (or `A<T> &`) as argument, it can never be found this way. So this option is not viable to your situation -- it's more suited to operator overloading.

So the only fix is to declare (and optionally define) the template function before the class definition:

```
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
class A;

template <typename T>
std::unique_ptr<A<T>> CreateA(int myarg)
{
    return std::unique_ptr<A<T>>{new A<T>(myarg)};
}

template <typename T>
class A
{
    friend std::unique_ptr<A<T>> CreateA <> (int myarg);
//          refers to existing template  ^^

protected:
    A(int myarg) {}
};

int main()
{
    auto x = CreateA<int>(5);
}
```

Note: It is possible to declare `CreateA` where I have defined it, and put the function definition later.  However, the code I have posted works -- despite `A` not being defined when `new A<T>(myarg)` appears in the source -- because `CreateA` is not instantiated until it is called, at which point `A` will be defined.

Comment: why does the code throw error if we define the class first & then the `friend` function

Comment: you don't need to mention the type, `CreateA` deduces it without you mentioning in this case

Comment: @AnkitAcharya no it doesn't, perhaps you are mentally mixing up this code with the code in your answer (which uses `T myarg` instead of `int myarg`)

Comment: @Anwesha see the paragraph of my answer starting "The other issue is..." , including link to C++ FAQ