# enable_shared_from_this for friend class

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, friend

I've got a class with a private ctor only constructible by friend classes using a create method:

```
class B {
    friend class A;
private:
    B(A* parent) { m_parent = parent; };

    A* m_parent;
};

class A {
public:
    A* createB() { return new B( this ); };
};
```

I want createB to instead return a shared_ptr to B. I'm currently solving it this way:

```
std::shared_ptr<B>
A::createB( A* parent )
{
    return std::shared_ptr<B>( new B( this ) );
}
```

But since there is std::enable_shared_from_this for inherited classes where my solution is declared as bad style I wanted to ask for a better solution.

Thanks.

Comment: As a side note, consider using `std::make_shared<B>(this);` instead.

Comment: It's not clear to me where you intend to use `enable_shared_from_this` or what problem you are trying to solve with it.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. Any other suggestion for improvement.

Comment: I'm using this structure because I do some more things before creating an instance of B. enable_shared_from_this is for creating a shared_ptr to the current instance where the above style of creating a shared_ptr is declared as bad. I thought there would exist something similar for friend classes.

Comment: I think you may misunderstand the purpose of `enable_shared_from_this`. It's purpose is to be derived from to provide `shared_from_this` which only exists to solve a specific problem. That problem is obtaining a copy of the `shared_ptr` for an instance *that already exists* and *that is already managed by a shared_ptr*. It serves no purpose in create a new instance of your class. Perhaps it would be useful if `B`'s constructor required a `shared_ptr<A>` instead of `A*`. In that case, `A` might take advantage of `enable_shared_from_this`. I'll write up an answer if this is the case.

Comment: Okay, that would be useful to unstand it fully. A is a class instantiated only once giving the option of creating a lots of B's (with shared ownership).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only scenario that I can see where `enable_shared_from_this` might come into play in your example is if `B::m_parent` was of type `std::shared_ptr<A>` instead of `A*`.

```
#include <memory>
class B {
    friend class A;
private:
    B(std::shared_ptr<A> && parent) : m_parent(std::move(parent)) {}

    std::shared_ptr<A> m_parent;
};
```

In this case, `createB` must pass a `shared_ptr<A>` but you can't simply use `shared_ptr<A>(this)`. This would cause `this` to be deleted when the `shared_ptr` was destroyed, but you didn't allocate `this` yourself. It's extremely improbable that this what you want to do. For example, if `this` is managed by an existing `shared_ptr<A>` then you will have two different `shared_ptr<A>` that don't know of each other, they will both eventually try to `delete` the same instance. Using `enable_shared_from_this` let's you get a copy of the actual `shared_ptr<A>` that manages `this` such that they are aware of each other (they share a reference counter).

```
class A : std::enable_shared_from_this<A> {
public:
    std::shared_ptr<B> createB() { 
        return std::shared_ptr<B>(new B(shared_from_this()));
    };
};
```

This can *only* work if there already exists a `shared_ptr<A>` to copy. For example, this would be a valid use of `A::createB`.

```
int main()
{
    auto my_A = std::make_shared<A>();
    auto my_B = my_A->createB();
    return 0;
}
```

This is *not* a valid use of `A::createB`. You will get an `std::bad_weak_ptr` exception.

```
int main()
{
    A my_A;
    auto my_B = my_A.createB();
    return 0;
}
```

Note that in the line `return std::shared_ptr<B>(new B(shared_from_this()));` I did not use `std::make_shared<B>` like I had suggested earlier. `std::make_shared` and non-public constructors are not compatible, you need a workaround that isn't part of your original question. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147027/how-do-i-call-stdmake-shared-on-a-class-with-only-protected-or-private-const) for more information on that.