# Is it possible to create constructors that return the reference to the old items, based on parameters?

Tags: c++, oop

Let's say there's a class:

```
class X {
    public:
        static X& get_instance(int foo, int bar);
    private:
        X();
        int foo, bar;
}
```

If I wrote this correctly then `get_instance` is a named constructor. Now here's what I'm trying to do;

Let's create an instance of X;

```
X& first = X::get_instance(3, 5);
X& second = X::get_instance(4, 6);
X& third = X::get_instance(3, 5);
```

I want to write `get_instance` in such a way that, when it is called with the same parameters twice, instead of creating a new instance, it should just return a reference to the old one. When the instances created with parameters (3, 5) all get deleted, then creating a new instance with (3, 5) create a new instance.

I imagined this would be possible by overloading the equality test operator and keeping track of every object the constructor has created so far. But this is C++, and there has to be a better way to do it.

Comment: What do you mean by "deleted"?

Comment: This sounds like the "flyweight pattern".  If so, look at [boost flyweight](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/flyweight/doc/index.html)

Comment: Store a `map` from arguments to X's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Herb Sutter's favorite 10-liner](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/My-Favorite-Cpp-10-Liner), adjusted for slightly different arguments and removing the lock:

```
static std::shared_ptr<X> X::get_instance(int foo, int bar) {
    static std::map<std::pair<int, int>, std::weak_ptr<X>> cache;

    auto key = std::make_pair(foo, bar);     
    auto sp = cache[key].lock();
    if (!sp) cache[key] = sp = std::shared_ptr<X>(new X(foo, bar)); 
    return sp;
}
```

Can't use `make_shared` since the constructor is private, unless you use one of the tricks suggested on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8147027/2069064).