# QEnableSharedFromThis::sharedFromThis() returns nullptr

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qsharedpointer

I have a `class MyClass` that should be able to return **this** wrapped in `QSharedPointer<MyClass>`.

It is my understanding (and experience) that simply creating new instances of `QSharedPointer<MyClass>(this)` is NOT the way to go. Instead The correct way to accomplish what I want is to let `MyClass` inherit from [`QEnableSharedFromThis<MyClass>`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qenablesharedfromthis.html) to provide the member function `sharedFromThis()`.

This member function should return **this** wrapped in `QSharedPointer<MyClass>` without all the bad side effects that would otherwise occur.

```
class MyClass : public QEnableSharedFromThis<MyClass>
{
   /* ... */
   public:
      void testSharedThis()
      {
         auto sp=QEnableSharedFromThis<MyClass>::sharedFromThis();
         if(sp.isNull()){
            qWarning()<<"SHARED POINTER TO *this* WAS NULL!";
         }
      }
};

void main(){
   MyClass *mc=new MyClass;
   mc->testSharedThis();
}
```

However when I run `testSharedThis()` in the example above, `sharedFromThis()` always returns **nullptr** instead of **this** wrapped in `QSharedPointer<MyClass>`.

I am new to `QEnableSharedFromThis` and I am wondering if there is something that I am missing, or what could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 3):

According to the official documentation:

> A base class that allows obtaining a QSharedPointer for an object already managed by a shared pointer. You can inherit this class when you need to create a QSharedPointer from any instance of a class; for instance, from within the object itself.

So you need to instantiate your pointer as smart pointer:

```
QSharedPointer<MyClass> mc(new MyClass());
mc->testSharedThis();
```

Or in your case use the equivalent to std::make_shared for Qt Smart Pointers:

```
QSharedPointer<MyClass> mc = QSharedPointer<MyClass>::create();
mc->testSharedThis();
```

Comment: Right. It's a good practice for classes like this to not have a public constructor but instead to have a `static QSharedPointer<MyClass> create();` function so nobody can make a `MyClass` that isn't managed by a `QSharedPointer`.

Related: To have the c'tor be (effectively) private while having `MyClass::create()` use `QSharedPointer<MyClass>::create()`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/8147326 for a clever pattern.