# Singleton object using unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the below CPP source code for creating a Singleton Object of a class using unique_ptr:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class A
{

public:
    std::unique_ptr<A> getInstance(int log);
    ~A();

private:
    static bool instanceFlag;
    static std::unique_ptr<A> single;
    A(int log);
    int mLog;
};

bool A::instanceFlag = false;
std::unique_ptr<A> A::single = NULL;

std::unique_ptr<A> A::getInstance(int log)
{
    if(!instanceFlag)
    {
        //single = std::make_unique<A>(log);
        single = std::unique_ptr<A>(new A(log));
        instanceFlag = true;
        return std::move(single);
    }
    else
    {
        return std::move(single);
    }
}

A::A(int log) :
    mLog(log)
{

    std::cout << "Called A cons" << std::flush << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
std::unique_ptr<A> mA = A::getInstance(5);
}
```

But when I compile the code I get below error:

```
$ c++ -std=c++11 try2.cpp
try2.cpp: In function 'int main()':
try2.cpp:45:41: error: cannot call member function 'std::unique_ptr<A> A::getInstance(int)' without object
 std::unique_ptr<A> mA = A::getInstance(5);
                                         ^
```

However I have exactly the same format of code in my project I get an error :

```
Source code Line 39: single = std::make_unique<A>(log);
```

Compilation error:

```
39:   required from here

single = std::make_unique<A>(log);

error: A(int log)' is private
 A::A(int log) :
  ^
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `getInstance` function be `static`?

Comment: Also, your code won't work very well, since once you called `getInstance` once, there is no more object in `A::single`. Perhaps you should use `std::shared_ptr` instead?

Comment: Lastly, your `getInstance` function isn't thread-safe.

Comment: std::move will transfer the ownership else it gives compilation issues

Comment: @Prakash you probably don't want to be returning a unique_ptr unless you plan to give the caller ownership of your singleton

Comment: This is roughly equivalent to fixing errors by sticking C-style casts everywhere until it compiles. Don't focus on cudgeling the compiler until it shuts up, focus on understanding what its trying to tell you in the first place.

Comment: There is a massive problem here due to incorrect use of unique_ptr but the compile error is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147027/how-do-i-call-stdmake-shared-on-a-class-with-only-protected-or-private-const

Comment: Noob question: shouldn't the constructor of your singleton be private? the only way to construct the object should be via the `::getInstance()` static interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: Don't use singletons.

Long answer: `std::make_unique()` uses constructor of an object it tries to create, and in your code it's private. Since it is an external function, it's not possible. You can create an object on your own and pass it to `std::unique_ptr` to manage, like you do on the line below the commented one.

The most important problem is, when you do `std::move()`, your class member `single` is gone. It becomes empty `unique_ptr` (aka. `std::unique_ptr{}`, it doesn't manage anything). With any next call to `getInstance`, you're essentially returning `nullptr`. You should use `std::shared_ptr`, which you'll want to return by copy or return reference to your `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: Oh, and of course your function is not static, but that was already answered.

Comment: "Don't use singletons" - completely  agree.

Comment: "Don't use singletons". What should we use instead then?

Answer (score 11):

First, the static issue. This:

```
std::unique_ptr<A> getInstance(int log);
```

is an instance method. You need an instance of `A` to call it on, but you can't get an instance of `A` without calling this method first, so ...

The reason for using instance methods is that they have access to the instance they're invoked on. Your method only uses the following members:

```
static bool instanceFlag;
static std::unique_ptr<A> single;
```

which, since they're static, don't need an instance. Just make the method static too, and you'll be able to call it without first getting an `A` from somewhere.

---

Second, the logic issue. Your `getInstance` method returns a `unique_ptr` to your single instance. The entire point of `unique_ptr` is that's it's *unique*: exactly one pointer owns and controls the lifetime of an object. When you returned a `unique_ptr`, you *transferred ownership* of the singleton object from the singleton class itself, to the caller. You even explicitly called `move` to make it really clear that this is happening.

Now, after calling `getInstance` once, your singleton is completely broken. If you call `getInstance` again, the singleton believes it has an instance (because `instanceFlag`), but the `unique_ptr` is in an indeterminate state. The only thing we can say for sure is that it *doesn't* control an instance of `A`.

Just return a raw pointer (or reference) to `A` instead of transferring ownership.

Answer (score 2):

Even after making the `getInstance` static, it won't compile because the definition for destructor is missing. Either give empty definition or leave it as default.

`~A() = default;`

Moving `single` will work first time and invokes UB for subsequent calls to `getInstance`. Instead return by reference `&` and remove `std::move`

`static std::unique_ptr<A>& getInstance(int log);`

```
std::unique_ptr<A>& A::getInstance(int log)
{
    if(!instanceFlag)
    {
        //single = std::make_unique<A>(log);
        single = std::unique_ptr<A>(new A(log));
        instanceFlag = true;
        return single;
    }
    else
    {
        return single;
    }
}
```

Inside `main()` you can get by reference 
`std::unique_ptr<A>& mA = A::getInstance(5);`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, as error log suggests, you are calling `member function` i.e. `getInstance` without any instance. Function `std::unique_ptr<A> getInstance(int log);` should be declared as `static`.

Declare it `static` as follow:

```
static std::unique_ptr<A> getInstance(int log);
```

**Note:** In *singleton pattern* `getInstance` function is always static function.

Following is an extract from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern):

> An implementation of the singleton pattern must:
>
> - ensure that only one instance of the singleton class ever exists; and
> - provide global access to that instance.
>
> Typically, this is done by:
>
> - declaring all constructors of the class to be private; and
> - providing a static method that returns a reference to the instance.
>
> The instance is usually stored as a private static variable; the instance is created when the variable is initialized, at some point before the static method is first called.