# std::shared_ptr template fails with C2440

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I want to enforce `shared_ptr` for a few classes. I'm using a `static` factory function to encapsulating private constructors:

```
#include <memory>

class MyClass
{
    public:

    static std::shared_ptr<MyClass> create() {
        auto a = std::shared_ptr<MyClass>(new MyClass());
        return a;
    }

    private:
        MyClass();
        ~MyClass();
    }
}
```

This template fails with [`C2440`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sy5tsf8z.aspx), (function-style cast) in `VS2017`, but works fine in `VS2015` and I have no idea why. A make_shared-version works fine in both but requires public constructors.

Any idea which option I'm missing?

Comment: You destructor has to be public, that's why.

Comment: Also note, that you have a dangling `}`

Comment: Factory functions should generally return `std::unique_ptr`. If the caller doesn't require shared ownership then `std::unique_ptr` is optimal. If the caller does require shared ownership she can simply store the return value in a `std::shared_ptr`, thus upgrading it. The factory function should enable both options and not force shared ownership on the caller.

Comment: Make `std::make_shared` and `std::shared_ptr` friends of `MyClass`

Comment: @JesperJuhl there is issue with `std::unique_ptr` though

Comment: @Slava Care to elaborate?

Comment: @JesperJuhl `std::make_shared` allocates a continuous block of memory for shared ptr, upgrading `std::unique_ptr` you are loosing that. This is not the case for OP though here.

Comment: @Slava That's nit-picking and I've never actually seen a case where that *actually* mattered performance wise.

Comment: @JesperJuhl requiring `std::unique_ptr` is nit-picking as well. I never actually seen a case where that mattered performance wise.

Comment: Having a static shared pointer might be up for debate. They should usually have automatic storage.

Comment: @Ron The function is `static`, not the pointer.  Also, static objects are handled at the end like automatic objects

Comment: @NathanOliver Right you are. That's flu side effects from my side. I stand corrected. Still something uneasy about having the shared pointer function for the whole duration of the program imho.

Comment: @Slava: (make)`shared_ptr` might delegate construction/destruction to other (helper) classes, so friendship is unfortunately not portable.

Comment: @Jarod42 in that case it should work as it is as it works in gcc currently IMHO

Comment: @Slava - my *point* of returning `unique_ptr` rather than `shared_ptr` was never one of efficiency/performance. It was one of giving the caller control of lifetime and copyability. Things that I find much more important.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I do not see any difference in having shared ptr to a single instance but performance. Control of lifetime and copyability is the same as unique_ptr can be easily upgraded to sharted_ptr

Comment: @Slava - Exactly, but you don't have that control/option if the factory function insists on returning a `shared_ptr` since you cannot downgrade that to a `unique_ptr` yourself. So, to give the caller the maximum amount of options for how to manage lifetime, the factory function needs to return a `unique_ptr`. And you may *want* a `unique_ptr` to avoid accidentally creating copies (and cycles) which you obviously can't with unique ownership. Shared ownership gives you more rope to hang yourself and it's nice to avoid those pitfalls when you don't *need* shared ownership.

Comment: @JesperJuhl it depends on what factory should do, if it suppose to create single copy to be shared then returning shared_ptr is intentional, if it should create new copy every time, then maybe it should return unique_ptr (and not always, depends on situaition). Insisting, that factory should always return unique_ptr is simply wrong IMHO.

Comment: @Slava We disagree. No point in arguing this any further.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I get that when the factory shall return a newly created object, the uniqueness of the ownership is part of the contract (and probably a very important part). That's a reason to use `unique_ptr` if you don't expect all users to need shared ownership. But if you know all users will need shared ownership and will upgrade to shared ownership anyway, it makes sense to use `make_shared`.

Comment: "_Insisting, that factory should always return unique_ptr is simply wrong IMHO_" The claim isn't just wrong "in your opinion", it's objectively, provably wrong when qualified with always: any design that relies on being able to call `shared_from_this()`, or any design that relies on `weak_ptr` (and I'm not talking about "design to avoid cycles"), is a lifetime management design that allows sharing, even if initially there is a guarantee that the returned `shared_ptr` has `use_count() == 1`. In that case you need to create a `shared_ptr` not a `unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like VS2017 complains about accessing destructor from `std::shared_ptr`, so you may want to declare `std::shared_ptr` as friend of MyClass. For `std::make_shared` you can use a trick from this answer [How do I call ::std::make_shared on a class with only protected or private constructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147027/how-do-i-call-stdmake-shared-on-a-class-with-only-protected-or-private-const)

```
class MyClass
{
public:

    static std::shared_ptr<MyClass> create() {
        struct make_shared_enabler : MyClass {};
        return std::make_shared<make_shared_enabler>();
    }

    // compiles fine for gcc without friend though
    //friend class std::shared_ptr<MyClass>;
private:
   MyClass() {}
   ~MyClass() {}
};
```

[live example](https://ideone.com/LFXFhs)

Comment: Thanks, got it. I was actually using that template without remembering the no-private-destructor part.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other answers: if you don't want to declare `std::shared_ptr` as a friend of your class and you don't want to make your destructor public, you can create a `shared_ptr` with the custom deleter. For that you will need some method from your `MyClass` that can access the private destructor and call `delete`. For example:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    static std::shared_ptr<MyClass> create() {
        auto a = std::shared_ptr<MyClass>(new MyClass(),
            [](MyClass* ptr) { destroy(ptr); });
        return a;
    }
    static void destroy(MyClass* ptr) { delete ptr; }
    private:
        MyClass(){}
        ~MyClass(){}
};

// later in the source code
    auto ptr = MyClass::create();
```

You can also declare `destroy` method as non-static and commit a suicide inside (one of a few situations when it actually makes sense).

Comment: "_custom destructor_" Do you mean custom deleter?

Comment: The additional static member isn't needed. It being `public` is also not a good idea. Still, that was the way I just wanted to add...