# Why does making operator new private break std::shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

I'm implementing a polymorphic type (call it `A`) that I want to have managed exclusively via `std::shared_ptr`. To allow using `shared_from_this` in the constructor of derived classes, `A` is allocated using `new` and then initializes a member `std::shared_ptr` to itself to manage its lifetime automatically. To help enforce this, I've decided to make the class-specific `operator new` private, and plan to use a `create()` helper function instead of `new` and `make_shared`. The design might look a bit funny but it makes sense in context for the UI library I'm working on. A minimal reproducible example is as follows:

```
struct A {
    A() : m_sharedthis(this) {

    }

    void destroy(){
        m_sharedthis = nullptr;
    }

    std::shared_ptr<A> self() const {
        return m_sharedthis;
    }

private:
    friend std::shared_ptr<A> create();

    std::shared_ptr<A> m_sharedthis;
};

std::shared_ptr<A> create(){
    auto a = new A();
    return a->self();
}
```

This compiles and works fine. The problem arises when I add the following code to the body of `A`:

```
struct A {
    ...
private:
    void* operator new(size_t size){
        return ::operator new(size);
    }
    void operator delete(void* ptr){
        ::operator delete(ptr);
    }
    ...
};
```

Now this fails to compile on MSVC 2017 with a rather cryptic error message:

```
error C2664: 'std::shared_ptr<A>::shared_ptr(std::shared_ptr<A> &&) noexcept': cannot convert argument 1 from 'A *' to 'std::nullptr_t'
note: nullptr can only be converted to pointer or handle types
```

What's going on here? Why is the `std::shared_ptr` constructor trying to accept only `nullptr` suddenly?

EDIT: Yes, in the actual code, the class does derive from `std::enable_shared_from_this`, but it was not necessary to reproduce the error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147027/how-do-i-call-stdmake-shared-on-a-class-with-only-protected-or-private-const

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I call ::std::make\_shared on a class with only protected or private constructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147027/how-do-i-call-stdmake-shared-on-a-class-with-only-protected-or-private-const)

Comment: @lubgr he's not using `std::make_shared`, so the answers in the duplicate don't apply.

Comment: @AlanBirtles That's right, I retracted the close vote.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When I tried your code, I got an entirely different error:

```
error C2248: 'A::operator delete': cannot access private member declared in class 'A'
```

And the culprit is this

```
m_sharedthis(this)
```

You provide a pointer, but no deleter. So `std::shared_ptr` will try to use the default deleter, which likely contains a `delete` expression on your type. Since that deleter is unrelated to your class, it cannot access the private `operator delete`.

A workaround is to supply a custom deleter

```
m_sharedthis(this, [](A* a) {delete a;})
```

The lambda, having been defined in the scope of the class, has access to `operator delete` at the point of its definition.

On an unrelated note. Your code as written is going to leak all those objects. Since the objects all hold a strong reference to themselves, how are they ever going to reach a reference count of zero? Consider using `std:enable_shared_from_this` instead.

Comment: I hope you don't mind I edited your answer to add an explanation of the VS error.

Comment: @AlanBirtles - I kinda do. You can post another answer if you wish.

Comment: @AlanBirtles - I mean it. Post and ping me so I can upvote. It's related to a C++17 change. On my version of MSVC it wasn't in C++17 mode, so no SFINAE but a hard error.

Comment: Done, only edited as my answer doesn't really add much to yours but if you prefer it this way that's fine.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! The custom deleter works perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

The cryptic visual studio error is caused by the `shared_ptr` constructor which takes just a pointer being disabled for un-deleteable types:

```
template<class _Ux,

    enable_if_t<conjunction_v<conditional_t<is_array_v<_Ty>, _Can_array_delete<_Ux>, _Can_scalar_delete<_Ux>>,

        _SP_convertible<_Ux, _Ty>>, int> = 0>

    explicit shared_ptr(_Ux * _Px)
```

The constructor is disabled as c++17 states:

> This constructor additionally does not participate in overload resolution if the delete expression is not well-formed.

This leaves the various copy and move constructors as the only single argument constructors, the compiler chooses the move constructor as the closest match but can't convert a raw pointer to `shared_ptr<T>&&`, the `nullptr_t` part of the error message is because the compiler is trying to use that as an intermediate step as it is convertible to `shared_ptr<T>&&`.

You need to provide a custom deleter to workaround this problem:

```
m_sharedthis(this, [](A* a) {delete a;})
```

As noted by others your objects will never be deleted as they contain a strong reference to themselves. You should either change `m_sharedthis` to a `std::weak_ptr` or use `std::shared_from_this`.

Answer (score 0):

You  disabled "anyone but class A" to create and destroy objects of class A. That means that  a temporal object of class A cannot be created anywhere else.

It's likely that temporal object creation you "broke" SFINAE pattern of template.

shared_ptr constructor accepts allocator and deleter that can encapsulate some legal ways to delete your object