# How to access private members of a class from it's private constructor

Tags: c++, function, constructor, private, smart-pointers

I have following class and here i'm trying to access private members of the class from private constructor.

```
class House {
private:
    int len;
    int wid;
    House()
    {
    }
public:
    ~House() 
    {
        std::cout << "destructor call" << std::endl;
    }
    static std::shared_ptr<House> house;
    static auto getHouse(const int length, const int width);

    void setlen(int lenth) { len = lenth; }
    void setwid(int width) { wid = width; }
    int getlen() { return len; }
    int getwid() { return wid; }
};

auto House::getHouse(const int length, const int width)
 {
    House::house = std::make_shared<House>();
    if ((House::house->getlen()==length) && (House::house->getwid()== width)) 
    {
        return House::house;
    }
    else
    {
        House::house->setlen(length);
        House::house->setwid(width);

        return House::house;
    }
}
```

I get the following error message

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   C2248   'House::House': cannot access private member declared in class 'House'  TestC++ c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.14.26428\include\memory  1770

Comment: May be [the error messages from this MCVE](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dc4f541198090f91) are clearer.

Comment: The majority of the code you've posted is not relevant to the actual problem. Why do you think `make_shared` should be able to call a private constructor?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Clearly clarity is in the eye of the beholder!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/8147027/241631

Comment: @Praetorian here i'm trying to construct the object withing  a class and use outside the class using smart pointers problem is clear with shared_ptr here.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ,@TypeIA thanks really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `House` does not have a public constructor, code outside the class is not allowed to construct a `House`. But you're trying to do exactly that, here:

```
House::house = std::make_shared<House>();
```

The implementation of `std::make_shared` invokes `new` to construct a new `House`, but `std::make_shared` cannot access the private constructor of `House`. To fix it, you need to construct the `House` yourself:

```
House::house.reset(new House);
```