# Verify at compile time that objects are created as shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, boost-asio, shared-ptr, type-traits

There are classes that I write (often as part of `boost::asio`) whose objects depend on being wrapped in a `shared_ptr` because they use `shared_from_this()`. Is there a way to prevent an object from being compiled if it's not instantiated in a `shared_ptr`?

So, what I'm looking for:

```
std::shared_ptr<MyClass> a = std::make_shared<MyClass>(); // should compile fine
std::unique_ptr<MyClass> a = std::make_unique<MyClass>(); // compile error
MyClass a; // compile error
```

Comment: I second what LRiO said.  In general, it is best (if possible) that objects are not self-aware if they are contained in a shared_ptr, or on the heap, or on the stack, or by pointer, or in a vector, or as a data member, or as a global.  As soon as they are self-aware of how they are life-cycle managed, they become a lot more constrained.  Unnecessarily so.  `shared_from_this` is (arguably) an anti-pattern.  But... sometimes it may be a necessary anti-pattern.

Comment: Ouch, in particular, at not being able to use a unique pointer.

Comment: You could initialize the owning smart to this in the ctor with a custom deleter and then arm it latter.

Comment: Is it a base class or a final class? Can it be used as a member of another object (of another, etc.), or an element of container, member of another object, as long as that object has dynamic lifetime and is managed by a smart pointer?

Comment: @TimRandall Not allowing the use of a unique smart ptr is a consequence of wanting to allow client to use weak ptr.

Comment: @curiousguy There's no specific answer to your question because I was asking in general. I have all kinds of cases with me, and when I asked this question (days ago) I wanted to know what my options are and whether there's something I'm missing on how to make this cleaner.

Comment: Another issue is whether constructors might throw **lately**: can you define a point in the body of `MyClass::MyClass(...)` where construction of the object is definitive, that is no other constructor of a super-object (here the difference between derived classes and classes having `MyClass` as member is insignificant) might throw.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make its constructor private and give it a static factory member function that creates a `shared_ptr`. Don't forget to document your design decision in a comment!

```
// Thing that foos the bar
struct Foo : std::enable_shared_from_this<Foo>
{
   // Returns a shared_ptr referring to a new instance of Foo
   static std::shared_ptr<Foo> CreateShared()
   {
      return std::shared_ptr<Foo>(new Foo);
   }

private:
   // To avoid bugs due to the shared_from_this base,
   // we restrict Foo creation to being via CreateShared().
   Foo() = default;
};
```

*(I can't imagine that `std::make_shared` would work due to the private ctor, but you can try it.)*

I've got to say, though, this doesn't sound like the sort of thing a class should be taking responsibility for. It's kind of programming backwards.

To steal [Eljay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4641116/eljay)'s [words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53949983/verify-at-compile-time-that-objects-are-created-as-shared-ptr/53950014#comment94738694_53949983):

> In general, it is best (if possible) that objects are not self-aware if they are contained in a shared_ptr, or on the heap, or on the stack, or by pointer, or in a vector, or as a data member, or as a global. As soon as they are self-aware of how they are life-cycle managed, they become a lot more constrained. Unnecessarily so. `shared_from_this` is (arguably) an anti-pattern. But... sometimes it may be a necessary anti-pattern.

I would prefer avoiding `enable_shared_from_this` and letting people use your `Foo` however they see fit, such as through a nice lean `unique_ptr`.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147027/how-do-i-call-stdmake-shared-on-a-class-with-only-protected-or-private-const

Comment: If you want make shared, add a private token type `struct private_ctor_t { explicit private_ctor_t(int){} };` and a *public* ctor that takes `private_ctor_t` as its first argument.  Then call `make_shared<Foo>(private_ctor_t(0))`.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Suppose. Meh though. Seems a bit leaky. Since the effect of not being able to do `make_unique` is limited to the `CreateShared` impl I think I prefer it how it is tbh

Comment: @light you misunderstand I think; the private ctor type is private.  Only way to call the public ctor is with the private ctor type instance.  Only way to get that is to be a friend, member *or* have it passed to you.  Basically it permits passing the token to make shared *in create shared*, saving a memory allocation and improving locality.  This is about make_shared, not make_unique.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Oh, right, that's better than I thought. Still feels a bit leaky with the public ctor taking something you can't create yourself, but it's acceptable to me ^_^ Does it it improve locality though? All it changes is the method of construction, and in a case like this (built-in type args) does that even really serve a purpose?

Comment: @light make shared means the addref on the shared ptr is in memory adjacent to the object; and as shared ptrs are often copied prior to being used, this is better memory locality than them being in completely unrelated locations.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I had no idea make_shared did that. Always thought it was just a way to emplace ctor args and avoid exception-safety issues(ish). Nais. In that case, we should definitely make this class make_shared-capable.