# How do you assign weak_ptr by passing the "this" keyword?

Tags: c++, this, weak-ptr

In my program Groups will have shared pointers to Subjects; and Subjects will have weak pointers to their Groups. I want the Group to have a join() function that assigns the Subject's weak pointer to itself. Below is the minimal code for what I've tried. How do I fix the join() function?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

class Party;

class Subject
{
public:
    std::weak_ptr<Party> MyParty;
};

class Party
{
public:
    std::string Name;

    void join(std::shared_ptr<Subject> subject)
    {
        subject->MyParty = std::make_shared<Party>(*this); // <---- PROBLEM
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto& BlueParty = std::make_shared<Party>();
    BlueParty->Name = "Blue Party";

    auto& Jane = std::make_shared<Subject>();

    BlueParty->join(Jane);

    if (auto ptr = Jane->MyParty.lock())
    { 
        std::cout << "I am in " << ptr->Name << std::endl; 
    }

    else { std::cout << "I have no party." << std::endl; }

    return 0;
}
```

The program prints out "I have no party". If the assignment were successful, it should have printed out "I am in Blue Party".

Comment: It seems like you're looking for [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this).

Comment: The problem is that Party is not self-aware that it is always owned by a shared_ptr.  That's not necessarily a bad thing.  One option would be to pass in the shared_ptr of the Party to join (could be made a static class function).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The line `subject->MyParty = std::make_shared<Party>(*this);` creates a new `Party` object that is a copy of `*this` and is managed by a temporary `std::shared_ptr`.  `subject->MyParty` gets assigned from that temporary `shared_ptr`, but `weak_ptr`s don't keep the objects they point to alive.  As soon as that statement completes, the temporary `shared_ptr` returned by `make_shared` is destroyed and takes the `Party` object it was managing with it.  `subject->MyParty` now doesn't point to anything.

The solution is to use [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this):

```
class Party : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Party>
{
public:
    std::string Name;

    void join(std::shared_ptr<Subject> subject)
    {
        subject->MyParty = shared_from_this();
    }
};
```

[Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4aa9245f6b5696ae)

To use `shared_from_this`, the object *must* be owned by a `std::shared_ptr`.  It's generally a good idea, in such a case, to mark the class's constructors `private` and use a factory function that returns a `shared_ptr` to a new instance so that objects of that type that aren't managed by a `shared_ptr` can't be accidentally created:

```
class Party : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Party>
{
public:
    std::string Name;

    static std::shared_ptr<Party> create()
    {
        return std::shared_ptr<Party>{new Party()};
    }

    void join(std::shared_ptr<Subject> subject)
    {
        subject->MyParty = shared_from_this();
    }
private:
    Party() = default;
    Party(const Party&) = delete;
};
```

[Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bddc44bfbe2b3219)

Sadly, this makes `std::make_shared` harder to use.  For a bit more info on that issue see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147027/how-do-i-call-stdmake-shared-on-a-class-with-only-protected-or-private-const).

Comment: The danger of std::enable_shared_from_this is that now Party instances are self-aware they are owned by a shared_ptr.  This may be a problem if a Party is created on the stack, but isn't a shared_ptr, and happens to be used in a such a way that something tries to get a shared_ptr or weak_ptr to it, which lands in UB land.  To protect against that, use a factory function that returns a shared_ptr, and make the constructors inaccessible using a tag key (because you still want make_shared to work).

Comment: @Eljay Added a section discussing that.