# Prevent creating a class only if shared pointer

Tags: c++, copy, instance, shared-ptr

how to prevent people from creating an instance of class, but only create a shared pointer? I am doing something like:

```
class OnlyShred
{
public:
    friend std::shared_ptr<OnlyShred> make_shared()
    {
        return std::make_shared<OnlyShred>();  
    };

private:
    OnlyShred() = default;
    OnlyShred(const OnlyShred&) = delete;
    OnlyShred(const OnlyShred&&) = delete;
    OnlyShred& operator=(const OnlyShred&) = delete;
};
```

Could you please confirm if this is ok? And if you can think of a downside doing this? The instance can not be copied/moved so this must gurantee that only shared pointer is around when someone uses this class?

Comment: `friend static` ?!?

Comment: just friend, sorry, I updated

Comment: please post a [mcve]. Something that actually compiles. How is `std::make_shared` supposed to create the instance when the constructor is `private` ?

Comment: [std::make_shared private ctor issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147027/how-do-i-call-stdmake-shared-on-a-class-with-only-protected-or-private-const/8147213#8147213)

Comment: I thought friend will pass to shared, will compile this sorry!

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number You are right. I can make shared ptr a friend too? But very ugly

Comment: @Vero No, you cannot, or you can, but it won't work because the construction is surely delegated to some implementation-defined method; it would be that method you had to make a friend.

Comment: @Quimby Thanks very much, I think I won't find better than the link you attached. I will go through it. In the mean time please if someone can think of better solution than the belows feel free :) Thanks very much!

Answer (score 5):

You can use `new` to allocate the class and then wrap it in `std::shared_ptr`, since `std::make_shared<OnlyShred>` will not have access to the constructor. A way you can do this is:

```cpp
class OnlyShred
{
public:

    static std::shared_ptr<OnlyShred> make_shared()
    {
        return std::shared_ptr<OnlyShred>(new OnlyShred);  
    };

private:
    OnlyShred() = default;
    OnlyShred(const OnlyShred&) = delete;
    OnlyShred(const OnlyShred&&) = delete;
    OnlyShred& operator=(const OnlyShred&) = delete;
};

int main() {
    auto ptr = OnlyShred::make_shared();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just a nitpick, but `std::make_shared` only makes one allocation, this does more than one due to separate allocation of the bookkeeping table in the pointer. But it might be the simplest answer.

Comment: Thanks, performance is ok I guess, I will only create instances before the main program start. Thanks a lot, I will use this :)