# Returning a shared_ptr instance of an object whose constructor is marked as private

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

What confuses me is that why `Foo *foo = new Foo(5);` compiles, whereas `std::make_shared<Foo>(5)` does not compile?

Here is the [code snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/3ajvbzcKv). Please pay attention to the comment in the code snippet.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
 
class Foo {
private:     //the user should not construct an instance through the constructor below.                    
    Foo(int num):num_(num) { std::cout << "Foo::Foo\n"; }
public:
    ~Foo() { std::cout << "Foo::~Foo\n"; } 
    static std::shared_ptr<Foo> Create() {
        #if WORKS_WELL
        Foo *foo = new Foo(5);  //Why this works?  The constructor is private indeed.
        return std::shared_ptr<Foo>(foo);
        #else
        return std::make_shared<Foo>(5);
        #endif
    }
private:
    int num_;
};
 
int main() {
    auto pf = Foo::Create(); 
}
```

Comment: In the second case, the call to the constructor is attempted from inside the make_shared function, which is not part of your class and therefore is not allowed to call the private constructor.

Comment: @TedLyngmo It not singleton-scenario. It's just hope the object would be automatically released and the object would shared between threads.

Comment: "I can see the use in the enable_shared_from_this case "? In another post of mine? There is no `enable_shared_from_this` in this post. The class named `Foo`  does not intend to guarantee there is only a single instance. The purpose of the object is to make sure that the object shared between threads would be automatically released.

Comment: @John That was in an answer to Alan. I can see the use of a factory function like this if you also use `enable_shared_from_this`. You can get automatic release by not using pointers at all. Is there inheritance involved? Polymorphism? More often than not, a `unique_ptr` is all you need.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I am really conscious about how `enable_shared_from_this` works for factory function. Could you please show me a simple demo snippet or a link?

Comment: @John Look at `struct Best` [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thank you so much! ***You save me a day!*** At first, I thought about `enable_shared_from_this`, but I can't use it well. See [my first post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72568272/13611002)..

Answer (score 2):

A static function is still a member of the class and therefore has access to the private parts.

Comment: You see, just like `Foo *foo = new Foo(5);`, `std::make_shared<Foo>(5);` is an expression  in the body of the static member method, too.

Comment: Thank you for your time and generous help. I fully understand it now. @spectras's comment helps me to understand it.